# ERROR: Unable to validate instance profile 'DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole' because no role exists with that name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to create the data pipeline in order to take a backup of DynamoDB. I had followed the below documentation for the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html

Still, I am getting errors as below.

```
Object:EmrClusterForBackup
ERROR: Unable to validate instance profile 'DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole' because no role exists with that name.
```

Also *DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole* is already there into IAM.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new role namely **DataPipelineDefaultResourceRoleNew** and assigned that role in EMRClusterBackup and it's fixed the problem.